# Easytrieve to cobol

Tags: cobol, mainframe, gnucobol, easytrieve

Can any one explain what is the replacement of below in COBOL

> REPORT RPT2 PRINTER PRT2 SUMMARY SUMFILE SUMTRN SUMCTL DTLCOPY
> SEQUENCE EXT-FUND-NO EXT-TRAN-CODE CONTROL EXT-FUND-NO EXT-TRAN-CODE
> LINE 01 EXT-FUND-NO EXT-TRAN-CODE + TALLY EXT-CAN-PRICE EXT-NO-SHARES
> EXT-REAL-AMT

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  You write a COBOL program that reads one or more inputs and produces a report.  Surely, you have an example of the output of the Easytrieve report.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a record in working storage to be written to the RPT2 file with this assigned data. Without knowing the types and lengths of these fields you are trying to print to the report, we cannot provide COBOL code to replace this Easytrieve.